# Python2 phoebe2 package

Tags: python-2.x

I tried according [this tutorial](http://phoebe-project.org/docs/2.1/tutorials/general_concepts) this program:

```
import phoebe

param = phoebe.parameters.FloatParameter(qualifier='myfloatparameter',
                                         description='mydescription',
                                         default_unit=u.m,
                                         limits=[None,20],
                                         value=5)
```

and an error is:

```
NameError: name 'u' is not defined
```

where u are units. What should I install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

`from phoebe import u`